# Pandas Dataframe loop and update from database

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

Given a pandas dataframe **df** which looks like following:

```
p_id | sales | salesperson | year
1    | 10,000| None        | 2017
2    | 15,000| None        | 2016
5    | 7,000 | None        | 2014
5    | 3,000 | None        | 2015
```

There exists an SQL table, **persons**, which looks like the following:

```
p_id | p_name        | from_year | to_year
1    | Brian Griffin | 2017      | Null
2    | Quagmire      | 2016      | Null
5    | Cleveland     | 2014      | 2015
5    | Lois Griffin  | 2015      | Null
```

I'm trying to populating the missing data in my dataframe from the SQL table.
A p_id can be reused as long as it's used by 1 person at a time.

What I've done is the following:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     df.at[index, 'salesperson'] = fetch_name(row['p_id'], row['year'])

def fetch_name(pid, year):
     meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
     persons = sqlalchemy.Table('persons', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=data_engine)

     stmt = sqlalchemy.select([persons.c.p_name]).where(
            and_(persons.c.p_id == pid, and_(year >= persons.c.from_year, 
            or_(year < persons.c.to_year, persons.c.to_year.is_(None))))

     name = data_engine.execute(stmt).scalar()

     return name
```

This works fine but it's very slow. For a dataframe of 30,000 rows, it takes about 20 minutes to map and populate the missing data.

Would there be a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Have you indexed your sql table?

Comment: Yes the table is indexed but it doesn't seem to make a difference. It is also quite small with only 100 rows in it.

Comment: It is very slow to query rows one by one. Couldn't you store your SQL table in a dataframe and use `pandas.merge()` on your `p_id` key instead ?

Comment: I agree with @ClemG., import the table into a dataframe, and then join the two dataframes together.

Comment: My issue with this is that I wouldn't be able to extend my matching. For example, sales numbers could be for a specific year and the p_id can be reused by a different person for a different time period. pandas.merge() won't allow to search which name used the p_id for a specific year. I'll update my q to make this clear.